# Jira helpdesk widget doesn't create an iframe when script is loaded dynamically

Tags: javascript, iframe, widget, jira

I'm trying to load the Jira helpdesk widget after user makes an action by loading the script Jira provides dynamically in code like this

```
  let script = document.createElement('script');    
  
  script.setAttribute('data-jsd-embedded', '');
  script.setAttribute('data-key', 'key value');
  script.setAttribute('data-base-url', 'https://jsd-widget.atlassian.com');
  script.setAttribute('src', 'https://jsd-widget.atlassian.com/assets/embed.js');  
  
  document.head.appendChild(script);
```

However while it shows in Sources tab in Chrome that it loaded the script, the associated iframe that contains the widget doesn't get created as it should happen normally, and I don't see any error messages in the console.

When I just use a `script` tag in the HTML file like this

```
<head>    
    ...
    <script data-jsd-embedded data-key="key value" data-base-url="https://jsd-widget.atlassian.com" src="https://jsd-widget.atlassian.com/assets/embed.js"></script>
</head>
```

Everything works perfectly and there are more additional resources/scripts fetched besides embed.js.

Why doesn't it work the same with creating a `script` tag programmatically in JS code? How do I make it work?
As far as I can tell the end result is the same - you get the same script tag.

EDIT I seem to have located the non-minified version of the embed.js and will include below

```
import MutationObserverHandler from "embeddable/widget/mutation-observer-handler";
import ReactDevTools from "embeddable/widget/util/react-dev-tools";
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/browser";

const jsdWidgetID = "jsd-widget";
const jsdWidgetName = "JSD widget";

class Iframe {
    el: HTMLElement;
    document: Document;

    constructor(iframeScriptSrc: string, embeddableData: {}) {
        this.createAndInsertIframe(document.body);
        this.applyCss();
        this.writeDocument(iframeScriptSrc, embeddableData);
        new MutationObserverHandler(this.document, this.css.bind(this));
    }

    createAndInsertIframe(parent: HTMLElement) {
        const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        iframe.scrolling = "no";
        iframe.name = jsdWidgetName;
        iframe.id = jsdWidgetID;
        parent.appendChild(iframe);
        this.el = iframe;
        const contentWindow = iframe.contentWindow;
        // check for null, which according to typescript dom lib >=2.9 can happen  (wasn't the case with 2.6)
        if (!contentWindow) {
            Sentry.captureMessage("iframe.contentWindow is null", Sentry.Severity.Error);
            throw new Error("Can't setup jsd-widget iframe");
        }
        this.document = contentWindow.document;
    }

    applyCss() {
        this.css("height", "1px");
        this.css("width", "1px");
        this.css("position", "fixed");
        this.css("border", "0");
        this.css("bottom", "0");
        this.css("right", "0");
        this.css("z-index", "9999999999999");
    }

    writeDocument(iframeScriptSrc: string, embeddableData: EmbeddableData) {
        const scriptTag = `<script type="application/javascript" src="${iframeScriptSrc}"></script>`;
        const embeddableDataJson = JSON.stringify(embeddableData);
        const baseURL = JSON.parse(embeddableDataJson).baseUrl; // added baseURl because lazy loading was not working
        this.document.open();
        this.document.write(
            `<html>
                <head><base href='${baseURL}' /></head>
                    <body data-embeddable=${embeddableDataJson}>
                        <div id="react-root"></div>
                        ${embeddableData.reactDevtools !== undefined ? ReactDevTools.scriptTag : ""}
                        ${scriptTag}
                    </body>
             </html>`
        );
        this.document.close();
    }

    css(property: string, value: string) {
        this.el.style[property] = value;
    }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const script = document.currentScript || document.querySelector("script[data-jsd-embedded]");
    const dataAttributes = script && script instanceof HTMLScriptElement && script.dataset;
    const isJsmWidgetRendered = document.querySelector(`iframe#${jsdWidgetID}`);

    if (isJsmWidgetRendered) {
        // tslint:disable-next-line no-console
        console.error("JSM Widget: could not render more than one widget on a single page");
        return;
    }

    if (!script) {
        // tslint:disable-next-line no-console
        console.error("JSM Widget: could not find jsd-embedded script");
        return;
    }

    if (!dataAttributes) {
        // tslint:disable-next-line no-console
        console.warn(
            "JSM Widget: legacy unsupported browser, jsd-embedded script.dataset was undefined"
        );
        return;
    }

    const scriptSrc = script.getAttribute("src");
    if (!scriptSrc) {
        return;
    }

    const iframeScriptSrc = `${scriptSrc.substring(0, scriptSrc.lastIndexOf("/"))}/iframe.js`;
    new Iframe(iframeScriptSrc, dataAttributes);
});

interface EmbeddableData {
    reactDevtools?: string;
}
```

Comment: Have you actually checked the result?

Comment: @Teemu Of course, the only reason I can't provide an example is it would require to make the data-key public.

The script in HTML version works properly and created the widget iframe, the JS script version does seem to load the script but doesn't create an associated iframe.

Comment: Well, the timing is different, the script tag in the markup is loaded and executed before page parsing continues. dynamically added scripts behave like a script tag with `defer` attribute. Maybe this script is called before it's parsed ..?

Comment: @Teemu Just tried adding both `async` and `defer` separately and in combination to the script tag in HTML, and it still works properly regardless.